# Google Drive Node.js - error while uploading files after update from node v7 to v9

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I´ve written a node.js script with the google drive api v3 a year ago and I was using node v7. Now I decided to update to v9 and update all of my node modules. But then I faced a lot of problems.

The first problem was that the auth was not working anymore. The official google drive docs didn´t update their own code yet so I found the solution inside of a random comment. As example

```
const readline = require('readline'),
  { google } = require('googleapis'),
  service = google.drive('v3'),
  { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library'),
  googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
```

Before I had as example:

```
google = require('googleapis')
```

Now after fixing the auth the quickstart file from google was working again and I was able to create my tokens and list my files etc.

Then when I reached my upload area from the script I get this error code:

```
Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit
```

I tried to google it in combination with google drive api but can´t find any solution to this. Is it possible that my code is outdated? Because with node v7 and the google modules from over a year ago it worked like a charm! :/

Here is my upload code:

```
        var fileMetadata = {
        'name': together,
        parents: [ foldername_folderid ]

    }

    var media = {
        mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
        body: fs.createReadStream('C:/testarea/file.container')  // <-- this is my own file format it worked before with the old google modules!
    }

    drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        auth: auth,
        fields: 'id'
    }, function(e, file) {
        if (e) {
          console.log('error: ' + e)
          return;
        } 


         //.. do something when upload successfully

    });
```

The test file I upload is only under 20MB so I think the problem isn´t related to the file size? Would be great if anybody has an idea to this!

EDIT: The code is working with a really small file as example under 5MB.. I think google changed their library and they don´t support any more single file uploads bigger than 10MB. I think you must use chunked upload instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working with a really small file as example under 5MB.. I think google changed their library and they don´t support any more single file uploads bigger than 10MB. I think you must use chunked upload instead.

However I can´t find any sample code for resumable uploads for node.js ...
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload

Maybe somebody has a sample code? I created a new post for this questions here:
[How to resumable upload with google drive node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055157/how-to-resumable-upload-with-google-drive-node-js)