# How to resumable upload with google drive node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Hey since google drive was changing their library I´am not able to upload anymore files bigger than 5MB with the basic upload **drive.files.create**. The docs told me that I have to choose resumable uploads instead. But google drive didn´t provide any sample code and aswell I can´t find anything on google.

Maybe it´s important to know that I can upload files smaller than 5MB with the **drive.files.create**

So there is no problem with the auth.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload

I wrote this POST request(Also not working with PUT):

```
 var fs = require('fs')
 var request = require('request')
 var file = 'C:\\test\\sample.container'
 var uploadUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable'


 var stats = fs.statSync(file)
 var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]


  fs.readFile(file, function read(e, f) {
             if (e) {
             console.log(e)
             return;
             } 




                 request.post({
                     url: uploadUrl,
                     headers: {
                         'Authorization': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                         'Content-Length': fileSizeInBytes,
                         'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
                     },
                     body: f,
                 }, function(e, r, b) {
                     if (e) {
                      console.log(e)
                      return;
                     }

                       console.log(`
                         Response: ${ JSON.stringify(r) }
                         Body: ${ b }
                         `)

                 }); 


 });
```

but I get as body result:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Request Entity Too Large</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Request Entity Too Large</H1>
<H2>Error 413</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If I would use as request url instead:
**https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable**

I get aswell an similiar message as body result:
**Request is too large.**

So anybody has a working code for uploading files with the resumable upload or maybe again with the basic upload? Or is there another way for uploading big files? I´am open for alternatives! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In other api clients (e.g. the Python one), resumable uploads are created by altering the [`MediaFileUpload` constructor with the parameter `resumable=True`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload#resumable-media-chunked-upload). The `node.js` api client is only in [alpha](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/), so it may not have built-in support for resumable uploads. You can try feeding drive [a stream](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#example-upload-an-image-to-google-drive-from-a-readable-stream), or simply extending that example `media` parameter, e.g.

```
media: {
  mimeType: 'some mimetype',
  body: 'some body',
  resumable: true
}
```

If stream and the above `resumable` don't work, then you won't be able to use the node.js client library to do resumable uploads, and will have to use the REST API directly.

Comment: I tried the resumable true option but didn´t work. I don´t understand why google drive had change their library.. Before a year I was uploading  gigabyte files with the basic upload drive.files.create and now after updating my node modules I get this ugly limit.. I don´t have exp with writing put or post requests I only used the ready library before. Would be great if anybody can post a sample code. Sadly I cannot mark your awnser as the right one because I need a working sample code for uploading as example with request module or other ways. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Did you try the [`stream`](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#example-upload-an-image-to-google-drive-from-a-readable-stream) example? You might also file an issue on their Github repo, asking about implementing resumable uploads.

Comment: I edited my post and added the put request I tried. But still getting the Request Entity Too Large problem. Something similiar I got with the drive.files.create. My file is only under 20MB and I have enough free space in my gdrive storage.

Comment: @LILBRICK1337 if you used the URL you specify above in your post, `.com/drive/v3/files`, that is for standard uploads. Per the API reference link you give, you need to use `.com/upload/drive/v3/files` for resumable upload

Comment: With the other url I get as body: Request is too large.

Comment: Try doing an empty upload first, where you just send metadata about the file. The response should give you the real upload URI, with an upload_id parameter. That URI should be able to handle the full file. In the reference link, they first initiate, then in a second request, upload the file.

Comment: Sorry but I don´t understand what you mean with sending a empty file. If I didn´t upload anything or if I use my file were the upload failed I only found in the response x-guploader-uploadid but no upload_id.

Answer (score 1):

The problem itself was related to the googleapi library for node.js. With v27.0.0 the basic upload was working again for big files aswell. Related to:
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1038

This is not an answer for how to resumable upload with node.js so you may keep this topic open until somebody post a sample code for resumable upload because even with v27 my POST request is still not working. Maybe you watch the github link from above because I asked there aswell for an sample code.

However my problem was only that I was not able to upload bigger files than 5MB. But this problem is now gone for me :)!